# SQLXMLBulkLoad via VBScript

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, bulk-load

I'm running the following code:

```
    Set objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkLoad")
    objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=SQLOLEDB.1;data 

    source=mySQLServer;database=myDB;uid=SA;pwd=myPword"
    objBL.ErrorLogFile = "c:\error.log"
    objBL.Execute "c:\xml\schema.xml", "c:\xml\addresses.xml"
    Set objBL = Nothing
```

I'm attempting to load a rather large XML file into the SQL table, however I'm receiving the error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LocID', table 'myDB.dbo.myTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

"LocID" is my primary key and Identity field.  Is there a way to prevent it from inserting `NULL` into this column, since I'm just loading data, not moving it and I don't have ID fields in the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before objBL.Execute

```
objBL.KeepIdentity = False
```

From the MSDN Article [SQL Server XML Bulk Load Object Model (SQLXML 4.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171769.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> **KeepIdentity**
>
> Specifies how to deal with the values for an Identity type
> column in the source file. This is a
> Boolean property. When the property is
> set to TRUE, XML Bulk Load assigns the
> values that are specified in the
> source file to the identity column.
> **When the property is set to FALSE, the bulk-load operation ignores the identity-column values that are specified in the source. In this case,
> SQL Server assigns a value to the
> identity column.**
>
> If the Bulk Load involves a column
> that is a foreign key referring to an
> identity column in which SQL
> Server-generated values are stored,
> Bulk Load appropriately propagates
> these identity values to the foreign
> key column.
>
> The value of this property applies to
> all columns involved in the bulk load.
> The default value is TRUE.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.  I actually found this yesterday while looking through the MSDN documentation on SQLXMLBulkLoad object, but I couldn't add the answer for several hours.  Glad someone did!

Answer (score 1):

If your doing a BulkInsert into a Database, you should do a Bulk Insert into Temporary Tables where each Column Can be NULL and i normally set my Size to VARCHAR(800).

Once it is in those Tables, i would then ETL and load it into my master tables.

Hope this helps you out.